# Solving $\frac{dx}{dt} = (x+t)^2$ by separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to do the following problem:

> Solve $\frac{dx}{dt} = (x+t)^2 $ by separation of variables.

This is where I am so far:

Let $u=x+t$. Then

$$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} + 1 = u^2 + 1$$

So, separating variables,

\begin{align*}
\frac{du}{u^2+1} &= dt \\
\Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{u^2+1} du &= \int dt\\
\arctan(u) &= t+C
\end{align*}

Here's where I'm stuck. How do I solve the equation $\arctan(x+t) = t+C$? [The arctan addition formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Arctangent_addition_formula) is not at all helpful, which makes me think that I've made a mistake up until this point. (Hence, a differential equations tag and not a "normal" equations tag.) Help please?

Comment: You could also use ${d \over dt} (-{1 \over (x+t)}) = {d x \over dt} {1 \over (x+t)^2}$.

Comment: It's interesting how different the solution is using this method vs. below. Can we know there isn't another form of solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply $\tan$ to both sides:
$$
u=\tan(t+C)\implies x=\tan(t+C)-t.
$$